# Initialise Service data before being used by components

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an Angular component where I am injecting a service:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private permissionService: PermissionService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.permissionService.loadPermissions();
  }
}
```

This component's template uses other components (child components) where `PermissionService` is also injected.

The `PermissionService` is the following:

```
export class PermissionService {

  public permissions: Observable<Permission[]>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)

  public loadPermissions() {
    this.permissions =  this.httpClient.get<Permission[]>>(`/permissions`);
  }

}
```

The method `loadPermissions` loads the permissions from an API into the `permissions` observable.

`loadPermissions` is called in ParentComponent's Init and from that moment on `permissions` observable is used.

How to make sure that parent components and child components use `permissions` only after permissions are loaded?

And is there a better way to do this?

The objective is to initialise a service, `PermissionService`, with data before is used by a parent and child components.

Comment: you could put an *ngIf on each of the child components...

Comment: Isn't possible in the child components to subscribe the PermissionService permissions observable and perform actions when the variable is defined? Not sure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think can this help you realize what you want?

```
export class PermissionService {

  public permissions: Permission[];
  permissionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.permissions);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient)

  public loadPermissions() {
    this.httpClient.get<Permission[]>>(`/permissions`).subscribe(permissions => {
      this.permissions = permissions;
      this.permissionsSubject.next(this.permissions)

    })
  }

}
```

Just you need to subscribe to the `permissionsSubject`

Comment: In your suggestion is this.permissions necessary anymore? Can't just use `this.permissionsSubject.next(permissions)`?

Comment: Look if you shure you have no asynchronous problem you can just get `PermissionService. permissions` . If you have asynchronous problem you will subscribe to the `PermissionService.permissionsSubject` and everything will working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `async` pipe and Angular will handle the "wait until available" part for you.

You can do a few things:

1. Change your `loadPermissions()` method to return an Observable value:

   ```
   public loadPermissions(): Observable<Permission[]> {
     return this.httpClient.get<Permission[]>>(`/permissions`);
   }
   ```
2. In your parent component, assign the observable to a property:

   ```
   export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
     permissions: Observable<Permission[]>;

     constructor(private permissionService: PermissionService) { }
     ngOnInit() {
       this.permissions = this.permissionService.loadPermissions();
     }
   }
   ```
3. In your templates, use the a combination of `*ngIf` and `async` pipe. You could also pass the observable to the child if needed as an input (or inject the same service into the child component.

   ```
   <div *ngIf="permissions | async">
       ...
       <app-child-compo [perms]="permissions"></app-child-compo>
       ...
   </div>
   ```